# Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel and Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

This is my router code :

```
router.post('/users/register',async (req,res) => {
       console.log(req.body);
       const user = new User(req.body);
       try{
          await user.save(function(err){
             if (err) {
               console.log(err);
             }
          });
          const token = await user.generateAuthToken();
          res.redirect('/');
       }catch(e){
          console.log(e);
          res.status(400).send(e);
       }
    
});
```

Generate Token Code :

```
userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = async function() {
   const user = this;
   const token = jwt.sign({ _id : user._id.toString() },process.env.JWT_SECRET_CODE);
   user.tokens = user.tokens.concat({token}); 
   await user.save();
   return token;
}
```

user saving code:

```
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next){
   const user = this;
   if(user.isModified('password')){
      user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password,8);
   }
   next();
});
```

Error :

```
ParallelSaveError: Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel. Document: 61109ecdc48220245c0ecaf7
    at model.Model.save       
    at model.userSchema.methods.generateAuthToken 



MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous>
```

This is the data I'm sending to mongo database :

```
{
  name: 'sdhfie',
  username: 'eifh_2397',
  email: 'example@gmail.com',
  phone: '+918329389241',
  password: 'sdfieu@92734',
  'repeat-password': 'sdfieu@92734'
}
```

I consoled the data and Data is sent but user is not saved.

I had tried most of the solutions available on stackoverflow but nothing worked in case of mine. Please try helping me out.

Comment: You using async/await incorrectly. You are using both callback function AND async. Choose one or the other.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky could you please elaborate a more.

Comment: Done I got it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Specifically `await user.save(function(err){`. You are doing await in front which you would do without passing a callback function. Effectively remove the function from inside save() if you want use await.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently mixing async and callback. Try updating POST handler to remove the callback function from save():

```
router.post('/users/register', async (req,res) => {
       console.log(req.body);
       const user = new User(req.body);
       try {
          await user.save();
          const token = await user.generateAuthToken();
          res.redirect('/');
       } catch(e){
          console.log(e);
          res.status(400).send(e);
       }
    
});
```

Hopefully that helps!